# IDEA custom inspection for missing return statement

Tags: java, intellij-idea, replace

I am working on a gRPC service in java and constantly forget the `return` after `StreamObserver.onError`.

I tried to write a custom inspection for finding any calls to `StreamObserver.onError(...)` which are not followed by a `return`.

My current inspection is highlighting ALL calls to `onError` and I don't know how to check for the missing `return` in the search template.

My current search template:

```
// Filter
// $Instance$ type=io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver
// $MethodCall$ text=onError
// $Parameters$ count=[0,inf]
// $return$ count=[0,0], text=return

$Instance$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$); 
$return$;
```

My current replace template:

```
$Instance$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$);
return;
```

Code example:

```
public void method(Request request, StreamObserver<Response> responseObserver){
    if (request.getRequiredField().isEmpty()) {
        // Do not highlight
        responseObserver.onError(Status.INVALID_ARGUMENT.asException());
        return;
    }
    if (request.getRequiredField().isEmpty()) {
        // Highlight
        responseObserver.onError(Status.INVALID_ARGUMENT.asException());
    }
    // more code...
}
```